# SimpleTemplateで value={{format_now}} としても format_now の一部しか表示されません

Tags: python, bottle

BottleのSimpleTemplateの中でdatetime.strftimeを使って、form内の値がpattern属性に指定されたパターンにmatchするようにしたいです

strftimeが実行された場合、`format_now`の値はformのpatternにマッチしたものになるはずです。
しかし、実際にブラウザでアクセスすると、`図1`のように西暦と日付だけしか表示されません
なぜなのでしょうか?

```
import datetime
import bottle

jst = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=9), "JST")

@bottle.route("/")
def index():
    now = datetime.datetime.now(jst)
    return bottle.template("template.tpl", {"now": now})
```

template.tpl:

```
% format_now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")

<input type="text" pattern="\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} (1[0-2]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (PM|AM)?" name="now" value={{format_now}}>
```

図1
[image: 実際の結果]

Comment: `now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%S %p")` の部分ですが、`%M` と `%S` の間のコロンが抜けていますので、`pattern` にマッチしませんが…

Comment: @metropolis 修正しました

Comment: ページのソースを表示させると分かるかと思いますが、`<input type="text" ... value=2016-08-08 11:14:20 PM>` となってしまっているので年月日しか表示されません。なので、`value="{{format_now}}"` とすれば良いかと(クォーテーションで囲む)。

Answer (score 2):

`value`属性の値がクォートされていません。
生成後のHTMLのソースを表示させると分かるかと思いますが、

```
<input type="text" ... value=2016-08-08 11:14:20 PM>
```

となってしまっているので、最初のスペースまでしか`value`の値と見なされず、年月日しか表示されません。
`value="{{format_now}}"`とすれば良いです(クォーテーションで囲む)。